# How to query the element of a vector which has a name that is an empty string?

Tags: r

Suppose I have an example where a vector has an element name that is empty:

```
vec <- c(3,2)
names(vec) <- c("","name1")
vec
```

I can call `name1`'s element `2` by doing:

```
> vec["name1"]
name1 
    2
```

but I cannot get the empty name element `3`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
vec[names(vec) == ""]

#>   
#> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

It is documented in `?names`

> The **name ""** is special: it is used to indicate that there is no name associated with an element of a (atomic or generic) vector. Subscripting by "" will **match nothing** (not even elements which have no name).

Thus it is better to make use of `make.names/make.unique` to assign default value for the names that are `""`

```
names(vec) <- make.names(names(vec))
> vec["X"]
X 
3
```